# Send window height width , toolbar=0 menubar=0 in url for webex adaptive cards

Tags: adaptive-cards, webex

I am sending a URL in actionset for Webex card API. This opens up in a new tab. 
is there a way to send JS parameters so that it opens in custom window size without toolbars?

```html
"type": "ActionSet",
  "horizontalAlignment": "Right",
  actions": [
    {
    "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
    "title": "Edit CID",
    "url": str("https://www.Casemon.com="+CID_ID+ "&Source=CaseMon")
    ]
                                        }
```